# Which is better: mobile/desktop code in same file, or in separate files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Say for example I have this markup...

```
<p class="remove-mobile remove-tablet add-desktop">This is a desktop</p>
<p class="add-mobile add-tablet remove-desktop">This is a mobile device</p>
```

...paired with this CSS...

```
@media and (//code goes here) {
   //code goes here
}
```

Would it be better (in terms of page speed, page load and so forth) to do the above, or would it be better to have the mobile code in a different file than the desktop code, and then use some kind of JavaScript to say "Hey, you're on a mobile device. I'm going to show you this file" or "Hey, you're on a desktop, here's a different file"?

I've seen some professional companies do the former as well as the latter, so I'm confused as to which is more optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote by Google : `It's better to have a responsive webpage not two different layouts`
As google says it recommended to have a mobile ready page and not to redirect ( or warn user to change to other design ).
And about the webpage speed there is not much difference between a non responsive layout and a responsive one.
P.S. : I forgot the place i read this tip but it was in mobile ready checker or webmaster tools.